# How to include special characters in SMS messages?

Tags: sms, special-characters, gsm

I'm running minicom to test sending SMS messages over a GSM modem.

The modem setting is as such

```
AT+CSCS?
+CSCS: "IRA"

OK
AT+CMGF?
+CMGF: 1

OK
```

The TE character set is IRA, and the modem is in text mode.

I only need to send ASCII characters ranging from dec value 32 to 126. However, I've found sending a simple character like "\" or "^" would cause +CMS Error: 305 (invalid text mode parameter value.)

```
AT+CMGS="+1xxxxxxxxxx"
> \

+CMS ERROR: 305
```

Anyone knows how to escape these special characters in the SMS messages?

Answer (score -2):

```
at^hcmgs="da" CR
message
ctrl+z
```

i test that